# Stripping data to lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Let's say I have the following data in R. I am trying to split them into 2 vectors/lists, each from each column, meaning (537715.4,537710.1,...) and (5741048.3, 5741051.3, ...). I have tried and turned to the looping solution. Is there any cleaner way to achieve this ?

```
>x
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1]  537715.4 5741048.3

[[1]][[2]]
[1]  537710.1 5741051.3

[[1]][[3]]
[1]  537713.5 5741057.3

[[1]][[4]]
[1]  537700.3 5741064.6

[[1]][[5]]
[1]  537697.1 5741058.9

[[1]][[6]]
[1]  537681.1 5741067.8

[[1]][[7]]
[1]  537686.7 5741080.7

[[1]][[8]]
[1]  537701.3 5741072.6

[[1]][[9]]
[1]  537709.6 5741067.9

[[1]][[10]]
[1]  537721.9 5741061.1

[[1]][[11]]
[1]  537715.4 5741048.3
```

Comment: `purrr::transpose` is handy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `base R`

```
matrix(unlist(x), nrow=2)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#[1,]  537715.4  537710.1  537713.5  537700.3
#[2,] 5741048.3 5741051.3 5741057.3 5741064.6
```

#### data

```
x <- list(list(c(537715.4, 5741048.3),  c(537710.1, 5741051.3)), 
     list(c(537713.5, 5741057.3), c(537700.3, 5741064.6)))
```

Comment: Also `do.call(cbind, unlist(x, recursive = FALSE))` OR `data.frame(x)`